# Adding framework to existing Cocoapods setup

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am working with a project where Cocoapods is used. I am unable to find any documentation for adding a framework to an already existing Cocoapods setup. All I can find are example on how to setup Cocoapods from scratch.

Any help? I'd like to add ABContactHelper via Cocoapods.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the pod to your `Podfile` and run `pod install` again.

For `ABContactHelper`, do:

1. `edit Podfile`
2. add `pod 'ABContactHelper'` to the Podfile
3. `pod install`

Comment: Actually this is the same. By specifying a pod, you are adding a framework as a dependency to your project.

Answer (score 3):

and don't forget to close the workspace in xCode before doing 'pod install', because if you don't, you can loose all your not saved changes, as xCode will ask you to revert the workspace to the version saved on disk.
Yes, I did it once ;)