# Adding new framework to existing Podfile using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, dependency-management

I have an existing Podfile that specifies one framework. I want to add another, using CocoaPods.

At this point, I have modified the existing Podfile (using Xcode) to specify the new framework. Following instructions in [the accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401483/adding-framework-to-existing-cocoapods-setup), I get this response in Terminal

```
[!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)
```

Can someone please put me on the right track, hopefully with simple step by step instructions for my simple brain? I've only used Terminal once before, when I installed CocoaPods and my existing framework, a process for which I successfully followed the tutorial [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2), but it was intended for creating the Podfile from scratch.

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you show your Podifle?

Comment: The Podfile contains only this: `pod "MagicalRecord"` ... I forgot that I had removed the spec I was attempting to add.

Answer (score 1):

A) Make sure you're putting the 2nd pod on a new line

B) Make sure terminal is in the directory of your podfile. Just open terminal, type:

```
cd (path/to/podfile)
```

You can get the path easily by dragging in the file from finder into the terminal window.

Comment: OK, I managed to edit the Podfile, adding the new pod on a new line. Then I did `pod install`, which returned this: `[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined local variable or method `“FastttCamera”' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x007fe53b8abda8>. Updating CocoaPods might fix the issue.`

Comment: Just tried to update cocoa pods with `sudo gem update cocoapods` and receive this: `Nothing to update`...

Comment: I deleted, then pasted (from the GitHub repository) the line in the Podfile for the new dependency, then did `pod install` again. CocoaPods took it from there and reinstalled the existing pod plus the new one.

Go figure--I can't explain it. The spelling was identical...

Anyway, thanks for the help, even if it didn't fix the apparent problem.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted, then pasted (from the GitHub repository) the line in the Podfile for the new dependency, then did `pod install` again. CocoaPods took it from there and reinstalled the existing pod plus the new one.

Go figure--I can't explain it. The spelling was identical...

Comment: "You cannot run CocoaPods as root". I bet that before you was trying to run `sudo pod install`, which runs `pod` utility as `root`

Comment: You're right, in one case at least. Unfortunately, I've shut Terminal down so can't check on the other several attempts, which yielded the same results.